# Сохранение activity при закрытии приложения

Tags: activity, android

Есть приложение, типа iq теста. За каждый вопрос теста отвечает свой класс, у каждого вопроса в тесте своя activity. Когда пользователь, например останавливается на 5 вопросе и после этого закрывает приложение, то при новом запуске приложения открывается первый вопрос, так и должно быть. Как я могу сделать чтобы при новом запуске открывалась последняя , открытая в прошлой раз activity? Я так понимаю нужно сделать @Override метода saveInstanceState. Только не могу никак полностью разобраться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот все расписано с примерами: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

В твоем случае, на сколько я понимаю, можно сделать главную Activity, которая запускает Activity вопросов. Вот в ней можно перегрузить onSaveInstanceState() и onRestoreInstanceState() так, чтобы грузилась Activity нужного вопроса. Элементарно, можно просто сохранить номер вопроса, как это указанно в статье, которую я линканул.

Одно маленькое НО. Чтобы главная Activity увидела, что сохранили Activity вопросов, можно воспользоваться:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Вот статья как пользоваться SharedPreferences:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

В целом я вижу такую картину:

1. При закрытии Activity вопроса, перегруженный onSaveInstanceState() сохранит в SharedPreferences номер вопроса.
2. При запуске главной Activity, номер вопроса будет выгружен из SharedPreferences (необязательно перегружать onRestoreInstanceState, достаточно просто выгрузить ключ из SharedPreferences в onCreate).